# Open local site in Delphi Android App (WebView)

Tags: android, delphi

I have a site located in the /assest/web folder, it contains an index.html file, a lot of * .js and * .css files. All I need to do is open the index.html file on Android, like Cordova or PhoneGup do with WebView. Perhaps TWebBrowser is suitable for these purposes, but I don’t need the address lines of the navigation bar, is there any component or other way to launch TWebView and place /assets/web inside my APK?

I use Delphi CE for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

No navigation bar is visible when using Web Browser for Android anyway. I think you want to make a WebView style application.
I can show an example I did.
[WebView Example written in Delphi.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yazilimtopluluguforum.YazilimTopluluguForum)

Codes of the application:
DFM

```
object frmYazilimToplulugu: TfrmYazilimToplulugu
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Yaz'#305'l'#305'm Toplulu'#287'u'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 268
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnKeyUp = FormKeyUp
  DesignerMasterStyle = 3
  object browser: TWebBrowser
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap]
    OnTap = browserTap
    EnableCaching = False
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 268.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    URL = 'https://yazilimtoplulugu.com'
    OnDidStartLoad = browserDidStartLoad
    OnDidFailLoadWithError = browserDidFailLoadWithError
  end
end
```

PAS:

```
procedure TfrmYazilimToplulugu.browserDidFailLoadWithError(ASender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Close;
end;

procedure TfrmYazilimToplulugu.browserTap(Sender: TObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
begin
  browser.Reload;
end;

function TfrmYazilimToplulugu.OpenURL(const URL: string;
  const DisplayError: Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
    exit(true);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      if DisplayError then
        ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
      exit(False);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmYazilimToplulugu.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  FService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
    TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService
      (IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(FService));
    if (FService <> nil) and (TVirtualKeyboardState.Visible in FService.VirtualKeyBoardState) then
    begin
     //temp 
    end
    else
    begin
      browser.GoBack;
      Key := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Within the application, any link other than the site address is opened via the phone's default browser. There are some configurations this way. Hopefully it meets what you want.